# Windows Server 2003 DNS: Double subdomains (e.g. sub1.sub2.example.com)?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

How do I configure two or more hierarchical sub-domains in Windows Server 2003 DNS management?

E.g.
I have a domain example.com and I want to create a subdomain configuration like:

```
subA.sub1.example.com
subB.sub1.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

If its just DNS, you should be able to simple create a new ZONE under example.com for 'sub1.example.com' and build out a tree like that.

Comment: From the dnsmgmt tool I could not see how to add a ZONE.  What I did do that worked was to add a new Host Record (A) and in the name field of the dialog box that pops up I entered sub1.sub2.example.com.  This automatically created a folder called sub2 with a sub1 host record in it.

Comment: That works as well, just replace "folder" with "zone" and we are doing the same thing:)  Glad it worked.